# convert date to epoch using a format string

Tags: perl, awk

I need my bash script to convert a string to seconds (since the epoch) using a FORMAT string, **where both the date and format strings are given by the user**. It seems it can be done in the BSD version of *date* like this,

```
date -j -f "$format" "$date" +%s //format can be anything, e.g. "%Y %m %d %H:%M"
```

but I use Ubuntu. Is there any way to accomplish this using bash/awk/perl etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use Perl, with its core [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) module

```
$ perl -MTime::Piece -E 'say Time::Piece->strptime(@ARGV)->epoch' 'Dec 25 2015 06:05:04' '%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S'
1451023504
```

Answer (score 3):

```
date -d "$date" +%s
```

For example,

```
$ date='2016 05 03 16:00' date -d "$date" +%s
1462248000
```

There's no way to specify the format of the date passed to `-d`, but there's no reason to do so. `date` uses heuristics which handle your date format just fine.

If the format is not handled by the heuristics, you won't be able to use GNU's `date`.

Comment: Thanks, but your $date is in the ISO format. I need to be able to control the exact format in a strftime() way.

Comment: None of that is true. Neither dates are in an ISO8601 format, and an exact format for `strftime` was provide (`%s`) and used.

Comment: Ok, but it still doesn't help me with my problem. Of course the output is %s, but I need to control the format of the INPUT string.

Comment: No, you don't. As I've shown, it works even if you don't. I explained why as well.

Comment: I know, ikegami. But as I've stated, the format is completely up to the user. There is no way date (or any other program) could automatically recognize the difference between, let's say, %H:%M and %M:%H, if a part of the input string is something like 10:09.

Comment: Ah, you changed the question. You can't use `date` for that. `bash` doesn't have any date manipulation functionality, but Perl has numerous ways of converting dates (including POSIX::strptime and DateTime::Format::Strptime). I don't know `awk`.

Comment: @Brikowski : if you have extremely specific requirements, then it's easier to first find a solution that splits out the numeric components you need - from there, it's a lot easier to customize it however you want. if u don't care about exact dates for DST switching, or historical events from 400 years ago, it's not that complicated to even just write a time parser. i've done it once and already nearly done witth the rewrote-from-scratch next gen

Answer (score 0):

You can use perl to convert time to EPOCH
but you need to change some variables if your format changes

```bash
perl -MTime::Local -e '%mon=(Jan=>0,Feb=>1,Mar=>2,Apr=>3,May=>4,Jun=>5,Jul=>6,Aug=>7,Sep=>8,Oct=>9,Nov=>10,Dec=>11);$date=join("\ ",@ARGV);print timelocal($5,$4,$3,$2,$mon{$1},$6),"\n" if($date=~/\w{3}\s+(\S{3})\s+(\d+)\s(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)\s(\d+)/)' Sun Sep 25 10:29:10 2022
```

Answer (score -2):

For `date` supporting `%s`:

```
date +%s
```

For Perl:

```
perl -e 'print time(),"\n"'
```

Comment: That gives the epoch time for now, not `$date`.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain myself clearly. I need to parse a user given date using a user given format string.

Comment: @ikegami - I still think my input serves the user well within the context of the question.

Comment: @ikegami - I respectfully disagree - it does not give the "complete" wrong answer -- see user's follow-up apology for not explaining himself clearly.  You yourself used part of what I gave in your answer so how can it be "completely" wrong (with all due respect).

Comment: Call it what you want, but it gives 1462306685 when it's suppose to give 1462248000. I call that answer completely wrong.

Comment: @ikegami - let's agree to "call it as we see it" and let us move on (respectfully).  Thank you for your input.

Comment: @Jens - With all due respect, I never mentioned the 'date' answer as being 'bash' specific but rather, since the user mentioned the 'bash' shell and Ubuntu (which has 'bash' as it's default shell) was also mentioned in the question, I thought it best to frame my answer to the question in that context.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: @tale852150 Didn't mean to step on your toes, sorry. It's just that the problem and solution are completely independent of the shell being used. I wanted to avoid that readers think your solution would only work under bash, when in fact it is more general. Sadly, many Linux folks know nothing but bash and are unaware whether their problem is bash related. They overuse the bash tag because they think that if they type it at a bash prompt it must be a bash thing.

Comment: The OP requires to *"convert a string to seconds using a FORMAT string which is passed as an argument"*. Your example doesn't allow the user to provide either a date string or a format string, and doesn't do any conversion.

Comment: @Jens No offense taken and I appreciate and acknowledge your feedback -- it was very helpful.  You make a valid point when you say that '... many Linux folks know nothing but bash...'.  Thanks again for your insight.

Comment: @Borodin The original question was edited after I gave my response.  See his apology in the stream of the comments as an example.

Comment: I am surprised no one gave me a 'thumbs up' for the Perl solution.  I tried awk also but that solution became cumbersome.

Comment: *"convert a string to seconds using a FORMAT string which is passed as an argument"* is directly from the original draft of the question. Your answer doesn't solve that or any of the edits

Comment: @Borodin You're correct.  I was just trying to assist the OP in any way I could be of help.  Thanks for your feedback.